# REST API is deprecated for versions v2.1 and higher (12)

Tags: api, rest-api, deprecated

In the last days i got this error on my magento.
Problems are on my checkout/onepage that returning to cart instead of success.

I saw that it can be a facebook problem with the upgrade (after 7th aug 2016) but I have disabled all extensions that uses API.

Comment: upvoted, seeing this issue with a Magento site that I'm troubleshooting as well. Happens when I try to switch payment methods on checkout, the error I get as a response is "Exception: Unable to set Payment Method", and the error in the question's title is logged into the exception.log

Comment: [**According to the Facebook API documentation**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog), the RESTful API is deprecated since version 2.0, and 2.0 was made unavailable as of August 7th. Are you sure that you have fully removed/disabled the dependency on the Facebook API?

Comment: Yes, I have removed everything... are 5 days that I trying to find out this issue. awful o.O

Comment: Am failing to log on my facebook

Comment: Buddy this is technical site and people discuss here issues in programing. With due respect, I request you to post this question in facebook blog. Thank you

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/162630)